# Superset with Trino Impersonation and LDAP

Tags: impersonation, apache-superset, trino

I have a Trino cluster configured to use LDAP and I want to use Superset to connect to it.

The Trino cluster uses HTTPS with a self signed certificate

I managed to configure Superset to use LDAP, that's not the problem.
I also managed to query Trino by having the following configuration:

sqlalchemy URI: `trino://myuser:mypassword@trino_server:8443`,
security extra config: `{"connect_args": {"verify": false}}`

**Now here's the problem:** Under the security tab there's a checkbox that says "Impersonate logged in user (Presto, Trino, Hive and GSheets)"
. I checked the box, and still the queries I execute run with the user "myuser" which is configured in the sqlalchemy URI, instead of the logged in user.

I'm using Superset version 1.3.2

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just wanted to let you know that I managed to solve this issue.

The problem was that I put this configuration - `{"connect_args": {"verify": false}}` in the "SECURE EXTRA" section under the "Security" tab, instead of in the "ENGINE PARAMETERS" section under the "Other" tab.

Answer (score 1):

There are two components to get user impersonation working with Trino and Superset:

1. A version of Superset that supports user impersonation with Trino.

This was added officially in 1.3.0, and since you're on 1.3.2 that shouldn't be a problem.

2. A Trino client that supports user impersonation.

AFAIK the only Python client that currently works with Superset to connect to Trino is [sqlalchemy-trino](https://github.com/dungdm93/sqlalchemy-trino). I couldn't find any specific changes made for user impersonation until 0.4.0, but I have gotten this working with the older 0.3.0 version.

There may be some other possibilities that could prevent user impersonation from working, but less likely:

3. Make sure that all containers have a working version of sqlalchemy-trino installed. This depends on how you add Python requirements, but I believe I've seen cases where Superset containers don't have the same dependencies, i.e. the superset_app container has the correct module, but not the superset_worker container.
4. Make sure that the HTTP headers in the requests going to Trino are not being modified. User impersonation works by authenticating with basic authentication but impersonating the user added in a HTTP header called 'X-Trino-User'. If the HTTP header is removed or changed, then the user impersonation won't work as expected.

Comment: Hi duty sloth! Any luck here?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay, I've been away for a while.
Unfortunately I still face this problem. As for the points you mentioned-
1. Superset 1.3.2 supports impersonation with Trino I believe
2. I use sqlalchemy-trino as you said
3. The sqlalchemy-trino version I have installed is 0.4.0
4. I believe that this is the problem, I just don't know how to check if the headers are missing, and if they are missing, what can I do about it?

Comment: By the way, I managed to impersonate another user by specifying the 'user' parameter in the 'connect_args' in the 'SECURE EXTRA' section, but that's not helpful as it is manual, while I want it to impersonate the logged in user.